# Can an Aes Sedai bound to the three oaths use sarcasm?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

All Aes Sedai are bound by a [ter'angreal](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Ter%27angreal) called the [Oath Rod](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Oath_Rod) and then sworn to obey the following [Three Oaths](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Three_Oaths):

> 1. To speak no word that is not true.
> 2. To make no weapon with which one man may kill another.
> 3. Never to use the One Power as a weapon except against Darkfriends or Shadowspawn, or in the last extreme defense of her life, the life of her Warder, or another Aes Sedai.

Does "speak no word that is not true" require one to follow this to the most literal sense of the phrase, or could you speak a false word so long as you know the recipient understands it to be sarcasm?

**Can Aes Sedai bound to the Three Oaths use sarcasm?**

<sup>Answers should be from the Wheel of Time series or interviews from the authors only.</sup>

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67496/what-can-aes-sedai-say-about-the-future?rq=1 I never got a satisfactory answer to that one!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes.

See [this interview](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=255). In the words of Robert Jordan himself (emphasis added by Rand al'Thor):

> **the oath against lying does leave room for sarcasm. It is intent and result that matter**. No sister can intentionally speak an untruth either with the intent of passing on false information or with the belief that false information might be passed on. Thus the careful slicing and dicing of words. But if someone were to hold up a piece of white cloth and ask whether it was black or white, **someone who had sworn the Three Oaths would be capable of saying that it was black as a matter of sarcasm**. But not if, for example, the person asking the question was blind and thus might well take the statement for truth rather than sarcasm.

Comment: Didn't a sul'dam try to force a leashed Aes Sedai to say a handkerchief was black, when it was in fact white (or something like that)? Saying that it was the wrong color wouldn't be lying by that definition would it?